# Why can’t I use sapply on a list of data.frames with non-numeric values?

Tags: r, list, sapply

I have a list that has 28 data.frames and each one of them from column 1 til 3 has non numeric values, and I would like to use sapply to make a sum from column 4 til 22. However I wasn’t capable of doing so... is there a way to ignore the columns with non-numeric values or another function that can provide me what I want ?

```
data = data.frame(x1 = letters[2:6],  
x2 = 'X',  
x3 = 5:9)

data2 = data.frame(x4 = letters[7:11],  
x5 = 'Y',  
x3 = 10:14)

teste_lista=list(data,data2)

sapply(teste_lista,sum)

return
```

```
'only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables'
```

Comment: In the tidyverse, you could use `mutate(across(is.numeric, sum))`

Answer (score 1):

Just like `sum(iris)` doesn't make sense (since there are `factor`s in that one), it can't work here. Perhaps this:

```r
data = data.frame(x1 = letters[2:6],  
x2 = 'X',  
x3 = 5:9)

data2 = data.frame(x4 = letters[7:11],  
x5 = 'Y',  
x3 = 10:14)

teste_lista=list(data,data2)

sapply(teste_lista, function(z) sum(z[sapply(z, is.numeric)]))
# [1] 35 60
```

Comment: Ok, i did give it a go, but R misunderstood something... he said 'unexpected ',' in "teste2=(Lista_Estados_masculino,'

Lista_Estados_masculino is my list so to speak

teste2=(Lista_Estados_masculino, function(z) sum(z[sapply(z, is.numeric)]))

i did put the exact sameway that you showed above.

Comment: I think this is the first time somebody has given the R process a gender ...

Comment: `teste2 = (list_Estados_masculino,` is missing the `sapply`.

Comment: hahahah, if could say what im trying to do... is a huge work and i came across with this daunting task of segregating by gender.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `rapply` with the specification of the class. eg `integer` or even `c("integer", "numeric")` if more than 1 class etc

```
rapply(teste_lista, sum, "integer")
x3 x3 
35 60
```

Comment: it did work, thanks  ! 

there is a way to do that by column or row, similar to the function apply ?

`apply(dados1[,1:3],2,sd)`, 

the number two meaning to do so by column

Comment: just use `rapply(teste_lista, sd, "integer")` will give results you want